# What is the simplest way to display content in a PHP/HTML website based on an if statement?

Tags: php, html, if-statement

What is the simplest way to display content in a PHP/HTML website based on an `if statement`?
In my example, the goal is to show the *follow button* only if the referer is Twitter.
I thought about the way below, is that a good way to do it?

```
   <?php
    if($referer == "twitter"){
    ?>
   <a href="https://twitter.com/Example" class="twitter-follow-button">Follow</a>    
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current approach? It looks okay. Some people find the [alternative syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) more readable, but it boils down to your personal preference, really. **There's no "best".**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a variable in php and then use the echo statement. You can send a ajax get request from your html using javascript. What you're doing also works.

Answer (score 1):

The more "Smarty-style" way of doing it (which is a good idea, even if you're not using templates) is:

```
<?php if( $referrer == "twitter") { ?>
    <a href="..." class="...">Follow</a>
<?php } ?>
```

In other words, exactly what you're currently doing but with less whitespace. I believe it's much easier to read this way too, but that's personal preference.